# How to remove option blue border color of select box

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do is if i click the select box and the dropdown list show the `blue` border-color of the dropdown list will be remove.

testing link: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/316/

script:

```
$("input, select, textarea, form, button").css("outline", "none");
$("input, select, textarea, form, button").css("box-shadow", "none");
```

css:

```
option{
  border-color: #ccc;  
  box-shadow:  #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline:none; 
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to get rid of the blue border that surrounds the entire options list.. not the blue background on hover of each option. If that is correct, I'm afraid you will have to resort to a Jquery plugin. Or write the javascript yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Do this:

`input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus, form:focus, button:focus {outline:0;}`

**Or** 
This will remove it from all elements.

```
 *:focus {
   outline: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
option:focus{
    background-color:#FFF;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
option:focus, option:active {
 box-shadow: none !important;
 outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and also see how to answer the question on Stackoverflow properly.

Comment: It is the proper answer, since select when clicked, and a dropdown is visible, is in active state. It means that active styles override focus styles. That is why setting styles in active is crucial for the style to work in all circumstances